# Sci-fi/Drama/Mystery movie with mini-stories and paintings that affect humans

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

There were several mini-stories throughout the movie. Each with the same set of actors. I think there were about 5 main actors, all Male, and all in their 40s-60s.

One story was about oil paintings were linked to humans. Such as one painting had perfume/acid poured on their face and instantly the human it was a painting of went blind and/or cigar burns on their eyes of the painting. Another painting was stored inside of a safe, and slowly the person it was a painting of suffocated.

The ENDING of the movie was 1 or a few people entered an elevator and hands came out of the walls to suck them in. The end. Credits rolled.

I would guess this movie was made between 1965 and 1985

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from? Actors etc? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like the plot of the anthology horror film [The Vault of Horror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vault_of_Horror_(film)) from 1973.

> **Five strangers board a descending lift**, one by one, in a modern office block in London. They reach the sub-basement, though none of them have pressed for that destination. There they find a large, elaborately furnished room which appears to be a gentlemen's club. The lift door has closed and there are no buttons to bring it back, nor any other exit. Resigned to waiting for help, they settle down with drinks and talk. The conversation turns to dreams, and **each man tells of a recurring nightmare**.

And the last story fits your description:

> **Moore (Tom Baker) is an impoverished painter living on Haiti.** When he learns that his paintings have been sold for high prices by art dealers Diltant (Denholm Elliott) and Gaskill (John Witty) after being praised by critic Fenton Breedley (Terence Alexander), all of whom told him that they were worthless, he goes to a voodoo priest and his painting hand is given voodoo power; **whatever he paints or draws can be harmed by damaging its image.**

The ending is slightly different than the one you described, though. Here's the trailer: